# Cannot set using Page Object Model in ruby

Tags: ruby, watir, pageobjects, page-factory

The user is already on `LoginPage` and wants to enter username using Page Object technique.

I have described the element in `LoginPage` class and using same element in step definition page.

I want to do some action on element using Page Object Model but when running using the feature files it throws error that "`undefined method`set' for "":String . "`

```
class LoginPage

  text_field(:userfield, :name => 'email')
  text_field(:passfield, :name => 'password')
  button(:submit, :type => 'submit')
end

Step definition uses :

And(/^a user logs in$/) do

on LoginPage do |page|
    page.userfield.set "username"
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the Page-Object gem, the text field accessor adds a method `#userfield` that returns the current value of the text field. It doesn't return an actual element. For that, you would need to call `#userfield_element`.

To set the field, you need the `#userfield=` method:

```
page.userfield = "username"
```